# How to make "cases" or "if, then" depending on comparison operator used in Sage

Tags: python, if-statement, operators, sage

I have some function which returns inequalies for example

```
s= solve(x^(2)<4,x) 
s
[[x>-2, 2<x]]
```

I would like to be able to convert this into a string "]-2,2[" to export into LaTeX.

How would I be able to check which comparison operator is used and then make a multiple case scenator based on that? For example

```
 if s[1].operatorused== "<" 
  then do stuff
 if s[1].operatorused== "<=" 
  then do stuff
```

and so on.

Comment: I've never used eithe Sage or LaTeX, but [this](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/developer/coding_in_python.html#latex-representation) link from the Sage documentation looks very relevant.

Comment: Where are the inequalities you pass to `solve` coming from?

Comment: @jonrsharpe For now, I manualy pass them, I'm using SageTex to compute exercises sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the operator via `.operator()` and do your comparisons that way:

```
sage: s[0][0].operator()
<function operator.gt>
sage: s[0][1].operator()
<function operator.lt>
sage: s[0][0].operator() == operator.gt
True
sage: s[0][0].operator() == operator.lt
False
```

To be honest I've fallen back on doing string comparisons in the past when it seemed more convenient (although you have to remember to make sure that `>` doesn't trip before `>=`.)

Comment: what do you mean doing string comparison instead?  This works btw, thanks

Comment: String comparison would mean examining the string on a character by character basis, checking if a character was a `<` or a `=` or a `>` etc. (probably using regular expressions). Also, if this answer helped you, it would be good to accept it.

Comment: @sweeneyrod don't worry about accepting, it's a common thing in some SE to wait a bit before accepting so other are more enclined to answer.